# binary tree inorder traversal in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to print out a binary tree I've build using inorder traversal, but I'm having trouble on defining how to pass values to the recursive function. Here is the error I'm getting:

> 1>methods.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   void __thiscall morsecode::in_order(struct letter *)"
>   (?in_order@morsecode@@QAEXPAUletter@@@Z)

Here's my tree from my header file:

```
struct letter
{
    string let;
    string morse;
    letter *left;
    letter *right;
};
```

Method from source file:

```
void in_order(struct letter *P)
    {
        if(P==NULL) return;
        in_order(P->left);
        cout<<"letter: "<<P->let<<endl;
        in_order(P->right);
    }
```

Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Do you have a function prototype at the top of this file? Is the definition of the struct below the definition of the function? If so, switch the ordering, or add a prototype at the top of the file. Your compile does a single pass over it, so if the definition of the struct is not above the definition of the function, then the parser will not know what "struct letter" is.

Comment: The definitions are in a .h file, the methods I'm using are in a .cpp file. I don't get any errors when I run it unless I actually call the function. I'm supposed to be passing the function a pointer right? I've declared typedef letter* ptr; in the header and I'm passing it a ptr P.

Comment: The response below will probably be your fix then. Check out what perreal had to say.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need:

```
void morsecode::in_order(struct letter *P) {
     if(P==NULL) return;
     in_order(P->left);
     cout<<"letter: "<<P->let<<endl;
     in_order(P->right);
}
```

to be a member of the `morsecode` class.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I'm sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake, I should have spotted that.